# Modifying an open source python program

Tags: python, open-source

I have an open source project written in python , it has some Forms and I want to modify a few things in the code and in the forms but it is my first time with python and I don't know what IDE to use and how to start ..
my basic question is can I deal with forms in python like c#, java ...etc ? and how should I start ?

Comment: What is your experience with python for starters?  What open source project is it? Also... a quick google returned quite a few results: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pycgi/ (one of many for "python web forms"

Comment: I am good in c# and java but never worked in python. it is an open source program about google maps called GmapCatcher http://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/wiki/User_Guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this project uses pyGTK, you *can* use glade which is a gtk forms designer, but it would probably add an extra layer of complexity that's really not necessary. Since you're already familiar with C#/Java, I'd recommend running through the [official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). Then I'd take a look at [this excellent PyGTK tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/). If you spend about a day really trying to understand the Python model and the "pythonic" way of doing things, you should then be able to easily modify that program.

While you probably don't *need* to use and IDE for a project this simple, if you want, you can use Eclipse (which you may be familiar with coming from Java) with [PyDev](http://pydev.org/). It allows you to write/debug Python programs inside the what may be the familiar Eclipse IDE.

Comment: +1 for zetcode. That site is really very good for any language.

Comment: I found it originally looking for cairo examples (which there are not enough of easily come by on the web), bookmarked it, and recently re-stumbled across it about Qt. I've found it to be one of the best resources for giving good solid exposure/examples for whatever the topic, without much "fluff".